# React useEffect Hook dependency array showing squiggly line for state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import NewsItem from "../news-item/NewsItem";

const options = {
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://crypto-news11.p.rapidapi.com/cryptonews/bitcoin",
  params: {
    max_articles: "10",
    last_n_hours: "48",
    top_n_keywords: "10",
  },
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "d8ef886044msh41d845fa9acd63ep1eb825jsnc6ceabb1a308",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "crypto-news11.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};

const NewsList = () => {
  const [newsData, setnewsData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(
    `https://crypto-news11.p.rapidapi.com/cryptonews/bitcoin`
  );

  const fetchBitcoin = () => {
    setUrl(`https://crypto-news11.p.rapidapi.com/cryptonews/bitcoin`);
  };
  const fetchBlockChain = () => {
    setUrl(`https://crypto-news11.p.rapidapi.com/cryptonews/blockchain`);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchNews = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        let { data } = await axios(url, options);
        setnewsData(data.articles);
        console.log(newsData);

        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error();
      }
    };
    fetchNews();
  }, [url]);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        className="bg-green-400 text-white py-3 px-4"
        onClick={fetchBitcoin}
      >
        Bitcoin
      </button>
      <button
        className="bg-yellow-400 text-white py-3 px-4"
        onClick={fetchBlockChain}
      >
        BlockChain
      </button>
      <NewsItem news={newsData} loading={isLoading} />
    </>
  );
};

export default NewsList;
```

All my code is here. I used state to fetched data and then pass it down to the child component . Buttons are use to change the url and i pass the url in dependency array as my effect depends upon the url . But why it showing yellow squiggly line for newsData state even my effect isn't depends upon it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch news after clicking on button.
You can try

```
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);

  const fetchBitcoin = () => {
    setUrl(`https://crypto-news11.p.rapidapi.com/cryptonews/bitcoin`);
  };
  const fetchBlockChain = () => {
    setUrl(`https://crypto-news11.p.rapidapi.com/cryptonews/blockchain`);
  };

  const fetchNews = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      let { data } = await axios(url, options);
      setnewsData(data.articles);
      console.log(newsData);

      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
if(url !== null){
  fetchNews();
}
  },[url])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: there is no problem related to button. 
my question is , Why there is demand for state variable ? even effect independent to that